# Additive subgroups of the field of fractions that are not fractional ideals

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, ideals

Let $R$ be an integral domain (commutative) and let $Q$ be its field of fractions. The definition of a fractional ideal of $R$ is an $R$-submodule $I$ of $Q$ such that there exists an $x \in Q^\times$ such that $xI \subseteq R$.

In order to build more intuition on why the "$R$-submodule of $Q$" condition is part of the definition, I wanted to find **examples of an additive subgroup of $Q$ that is *not* an $R$-submodule of $Q$**, i.e. not closed under $R$-multiplication.

If we take $R = \mathbb{Q}$ then $Q \cong \mathbb{Q}$, and any subring of $\mathbb{Q}$ that is not an ideal, e.g. $2\mathbb{Z}$, will do as an example (because it will not be a $\mathbb{Q}$-submodule of $\mathbb{Q}$).

Now, are there any examples (of additive subrings of $Q$ that are not $R$-modules) when the inclusion $R \hookrightarrow Q $ is strict (i.e. $R$ and $Q$ are not the same)?

Comment: $2\mathbb Z$ **is** a $\mathbb Z$-submodule of $\mathbb Q$ since that's the same as being a subgroup. Also it's an ideal, maybe you meant $\frac12\mathbb Z$ (although that is still a $\mathbb Z$-submodule, a fractional ideal in fact)? Any integral domain that is not a field is one for which $R\hookrightarrow Q$ is strict.

Comment: @HilbertJr. In my example, I'm taking $R = Q = \mathbb{Q}$ (the field of fractions of the rationals is isomorphic to the rationals again), where $2\mathbb{Z}$ is not a $\mathbb{Q}$-submodule of $\mathbb{Q}$ (it is not an ideal of $\mathbb{Q}$).

Comment: @HilbertJr. Regarding the second part, yes of course, any integral domain that is not a field generates a bigger field of fractions, but what I'm asking for is whether in such a case there can exist an additive subring of the field of fractions that is not an R-module. I've edited the question to make it clearer (hopefully).

Comment: What about $R=\mathbb Z[i]$? (In my opinion your question is irrelevant for the understanding of fractional ideals. The module requirement from the definition is simply for making $xI$ an ideal of $R$.)

Comment: @user26857 I see, in your example $Q = \mathbb{Q}(i)$ we could take the subring $\mathbb{Q}$, right? In my opinion, seeing non-examples of a definition is just as helpful or perhaps even more helpful than seeing examples to build intuition about what it is precisely that we require.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested by @user26857, an example would be $R = \mathbb{Z}[i]$, $Q = \mathbb{Q}(i)$ and take the subring $I := \mathbb{Z} \subseteq \mathbb{Q}(i)$.
This is not an $R$-module because it is not closed under multiplication by $i \in R$.
Note that this is a "minimal example" in the sense that it does satisfy the other condition, namely we have $1I \subseteq R$.

This is a special case of the class of examples $R = S[x]$ taking any subring $T \subseteq S \subsetneq Q$ or even $\frac{1}{x}T$ where $x \in S^*$.